# How to find all columns equal to a given column?

Tags: r

Given a matrix and a certain column index, how can I find all columns equal to that column (or at most t columns vectors equal to that column).

For example:

```
m=matrix(data=c(2,2,2,2,3,0,2,2), ncol = 4)
```

equal columns are `1 & 2 & 4`

If column `index=1` I can retrieve `2 & 4`

If `t=1` I will get just the second column `2` or the `4-th` column .

Comment: How do you even have column 4 when your `ncol` is 3 ?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please provide a [reproducible example in r](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example). The link I provided, will tell you how. Moreover, please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and visit [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Cheers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming you have a typo with how you're creating your example matrix. Here's a straightforward way to get the indices you want.

```
m=matrix(data=c(2,2,2,2,3,0,2,2), ncol=4)

equal_cols = function(m, col_index){
    out = NULL
    for (i in (1:NCOL(m))[-col_index]){
        if (all(m[,col_index] == m[,i]))
            out = c(out, i)
        }
    return (out)
    }

equal_cols(m, 1)
# 2 4
```

Answer (score 0):

Given that ncol =4, uou could use the apply and which function:

```
m <- matrix(data=c(2,2,2,2,3,0,2,2), ncol=4)
index <- 1

x <- apply(m,2,FUN=function(x){all(x==m[,index])}) %>% which()
x
[1] 1 2 4
```

But then the index column is included. It can easily be removed using

```
x[x!=index]
[1] 2 4
```

Comment: Hey, this is a great solution, but I think `all(x == m[, index])` in FUN is more concise.

Comment: Thanks you all again . Plz mister how can I get a sub result optimally ( t first equal columns to that column index ) . In my final project , data will be large. I can't go line per line.

Comment: @TouMou I think `while()` loop will achieve what you want. You can adapt @mickey's `for()` loop to a `while()` version and set when to break the loop by a conditional statement.

Comment: Great , i do it like this : equal_cols = function(m, col_index , t){
  out = NULL
  for (i in (1:NCOL(m))[-col_index]){
    if (all(m[,col_index] == m[,i]))
      out = c(out, i)
    if (length(out) == t ) break
  }
  return (out)
}

Comment: @DarrenTsai Nice, I agree. I've updated the answer to use the all() function instead. It's definitely more concise.